# How to avoid turtles revisiting the patch on which they were last time?

Tags: netlogo

Turtles stay on patches for 60 ticks, and then move to another target patch. How to avoid turtles revisiting the patch on which they were last time? Thanks

Hi Seth and Frank,

Thank you very much for your reply. I am sorry I did not describe the questions in detail.

Turtles will not visit the patch that they were on the last tick, and will move to another nearest patch instead in next tick. The following codes mean they find the nearest patch, and move on to it.

What I would want to do is the turtle will find the nearest patch again in the next tick. They will move to other alternative that is nearest to themselves, if the nearest patch is still the same one that they were on the last tick. Thanks

```
let closest-leaf min-one-of (patches in-radius 1 with [pcolor = lime]) [distance myself]

face closest-leaf

fd distance closest-leaf
```

Comment: Only the patch they were on the last tick, or all patches they were on in all previous ticks...?

Comment: Hi Seth and Frank, Thank you very much for your reply. Turtles will not visit the patch they were on the last tick, and will move to another nearest patch instead. Please look at the codes above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `get-target` reporter.

```
to-report get-target  ;;turtle proc
  let %close patches in-radius 1 with [pcolor = lime and self != [patch-here] of myself]
  ifelse (any? %close) [
    report min-one-of %close [distance myself]
  ] [
    report nobody
  ]
end
```

Now you can easily change your mind about how to pick a target. You can then move to the target (if one exists).

```
to move  ;; turtle proc
  let %target get-target
  ifelse (%target = nobody) [
    ;handle this case
  ] [
    face %target move-to %target
  ]
end
```

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you very much for your reply. I run the code, and there is an error. this code can't be run by a patch
error while fly 1 running AND
  called by procedure GET-TARGET
  called by procedure SHORT-HOP
  called by procedure MOVE-FLIES
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'Run' Something is wrong with pcolor = lime and self != patch-here. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. A patch cannot run `patch-here`.  Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

A good way is to have a turtles-own variable of patches visited that can be maintained (remember to initialize it to the empty list when you create the turtle).

```
turtles-own [ patches-visited ]

to setup
  ...
  ask turtles [ set patches-visited [] ]
  ...
end

to move
  let potential-targets filter [ not member? ? patches-visited ] target-patches
  let target-patch one-of potential-targets

  if target-patch != NOBODY [
    set patches-visited fput target-patch patches-visited
    ; move to target patch
  ]
end
```

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you for your answer. I think your answer refers to all patches they were on in all previous ticks. What I would want to do is the turtle will find the nearest patch again in the next tick. They will move to other alternative that is nearest to themselves, if the nearest patch is still the same one that they were on the last tick. Thanks